# Excel formula returns zero yet cell.Value = 0 returns False

Tags: vba

Have a simple formula where I'm trying to hide rows in a column of formulas.  I want to hide each row that is zero or blank.  However, it won't hide the rows that have a zero from a formula.  What should I change?  Here's my code

```
Sub HideRows2()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("a7:a122")
            If IsEmpty(cell) Then
             If cell.Value = 0 Then
                      cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `If IsEmpty(cell)`?  What do you expect the value of the empty cell to be?

Comment: Try `If cell.Value + 0 = 0` )

Answer (score 1):

This will hide/show the row without using an If statement.

```
cell.EntireRow.Hidden = Int(cell.Value) = 0
```

Comment: Clever use of a comparison that evaluates to a Boolean!